# Order of membership types on contribution page not correct

Tags: civimember, contribution-page

Does anyone have any ideas why the order of membership types wouldn't be correct on a contribution page? The order in the contribution page settings matches the order defined in Administration - Membership Types, but the display of the membership types is in a different order on the public facing page. I can make the order change by changing the order of membership types or unselecting some of the membership types on the contribution page, but not so that they are actually in the right order. I also note that trying to change the order in the membership types doesn't work right (sometimes membership types don't move at all, sometimes they move in unpredictable ways).

Any thoughts on why this might be? I cannot reproduce this on the demo site. 5.35 on Drupal 7, [here is the contribution page](https://secure.wildsight.ca/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=7). No default membership type set on the contribution page and we do have some old disabled membership types as well.

Comment: if you have access to DB check the 'weight' column in civicrm_membership_type table. i think i recall a case where we ended up with lots of double ups

Comment: Thanks! Yes, there sure were double ups, most of them all had the order = 1. You can actually see and edit these on the edit screen for each membership type.

Answer (score 4):

Turns out we had almost all of our membership types with order = 1. Using the up and down arrows didn't seem to fix this, but going through one by one multiple times and editing the order values for each membership type did eventually sort this out. You have to edit and save the contribution page to have the change in order show up.